# What code do I "comment out" to remove the loop from this Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

In my theme (which is the amazing GeneratePress) there is, of course, an archive.php file.

I have custom taxonomy which (to save a long and boring discussion) needs to have its' loop removed or hidden.

So, here's the archive.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * @package GeneratePress
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'content' ); ?>>
        <main id="main" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'main' ); ?>>
            <?php
            /**
             * generate_before_main_content hook.
             *
             * @since 0.1
             */
            do_action( 'generate_before_main_content' );

            if ( have_posts() ) :

                /**
                 * generate_archive_title hook.
                 *
                 * @since 0.1
                 *
                 * @hooked generate_archive_title - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'generate_archive_title' );

                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;

                /**
                 * generate_after_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @since 2.3
                 */
                do_action( 'generate_after_loop' );

                generate_content_nav( 'nav-below' );

            else :

                get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );

            endif;

            /**
             * generate_after_main_content hook.
             *
             * @since 0.1
             */
            do_action( 'generate_after_main_content' );
            ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php
    /**
     * generate_after_primary_content_area hook.
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    do_action( 'generate_after_primary_content_area' );

    generate_construct_sidebars();

get_footer();
```

Can anyone recommend what to comment-out?

My custom taxonomy is called "countries" so I guess my file should be called "archive-countries.php" which is what WordPress will look for in the hierarchical order.

Thank you for all help with this.

PS - I think the area to "comment out" should be the entire [if] < > [endif] section...

Comment: You could actually just try removing/replacing the whole "if ( have_posts() )" block there? But yes, that's the main loop area there.

Comment: So, there's no "bad practice" in doing that - I guess I just want to make sure I am doing it right.... (and thanks BTW)

Comment: I didn't say it's a good thing to remove the loop there. I just responded to what's asked in the question - "what to comment-out".